# Change the Sherlock TabBar background color

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, tabbar

I'm trying to customize the SherlockTabBar and got stuck on changing tab background color. I've already used the 'ActionBarStyle Generator' and copied from there just the resources that I'm interested to change. For now I managed to change the selected tab indicator, but I don't know how to change tab background along with the tab indicator.
My code for custom style looks like this:

```html
  <style name="Theme.Custom" parent="style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyActionBarTabStyle" parent="style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbarselector</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
  </style>
```

and the selector :

```html
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_customstyle"/>
  <item android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_customstyle" />
  <item android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_customstyle" />
</selector>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: hey, man try TOOLBAR introduced in api 21, super easy to use and you can modify color,height of Toolbar. just suggesting out another option .check the link out [toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html)

Comment: I'm stuck on SherlockTabBar, it wasn't my choice to use it. Thanks anyway for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Hemant for lead, but the code you posted it will change the actionbar background color not the tabbar. But looking at that code it came to my mind to set it programmatically and not by style, as following:

```
SupportActionBar.SetStackedBackgroundDrawable(Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.ab_stacked_solid_customstyle));
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try, this to change the color . use ARgb (#AARRGGBB) to generate Color. Alpha (AA) is for transparency or RGB (#RRGGBB) with standard colors.

`getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FF00853c")));`

hope that works ..